# Word to describe willingness to judge others?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think of a word that would describe someone who is willing to judge or critique others. Not in the negative sense of being judgemental, but willing to review tasks performed by others and judge if the task was done correctly and report back when it wasn't. Someone willing to be a competition judge or referee would be a good example of the type of character trait I'm trying to describe.

Comment: *critical*  or *judicial*?

Comment: I’d want a judge to be ***circumspect***

Answer (score 1):

A person with analytical character traits would be a reviewer or an appraiser.

> #### Analytical - Oxford Dictionary
>
> Relating to or using analysis or logical reasoning:
>
> “analytical methods”
>
> “a suave, analytical type who missed his calling as a lawyer”
>
> Source link: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/analytical

---

> #### Reviewer - Oxford Dictionary
>
> 1)  A person who writes critical appraisals of books, plays, movies, etc., for publication.
>
> 2) A person who formally assesses or examines something with a view to changing it if necessary
>
> Source link: >http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definitions/american_english/analytical

---

> #### Appraiser - Vocabulary.com
>
> 1) One who estimates officially the worth or value or quality of things.
>
> - Type of: evaluator, judge
> - an authority who is able to estimate worth or quality
>
> Source link: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/appraiser